# Can not import IterativeImputer from sklearn.impute

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data

I have a dataset with a column contains missing values which has relatively high correlation with another columns. I want to use IterativeImputer from sklearn.impute but I receive this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'IterativeImputer'
```

I upgraded my conda, my scikitlearn package and it is not resolved yet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IterativeImputer is only available in scikit-learn 0.21, which as of April 2019 is only released as a developer version, not as stable.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem even with the 0.21 version of sklearn. You need to add an other import

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
```

Comment: This suggestion solved that issue on a Colab notebook.